# llamado de una funcion desde otro archivo php

Tags: php, javascript, html, sql

```
$bd= new DB();
$conectar = $bd->conectar();
function extFolio($folio)
{
    $query = "select FolioParticipanteCG from participantes where FolioParticipanteCG = '".$folio."'";
    $folio=mysqli_query($conectar,$query)or die("Error al seleccionar folio".mysqli_error());//En esta linea es donde me genera el error 
    $folio=mysqli_num_rows($folio);
    return $folio; 
}
```

Este es el error Undefined variable: conectar 
soy nuevo en php entonces creo que es porque la variable conectar la necesito instanciar dentro de la funcion pero yo quisiera usarla de manera global y esa misma funcion esta en otro archivo php el cual se llama clas_conex.class.php pero no veo el problema ya que hago lo del require. Agradecería su ayuda o alguna opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Si la variable `$conectar` la tienes en un fichero, `conexion.php` por ejemplo:

```
<?php
$dbServername = "localhost";
$dbUsername = "username";
$dbPassword = "pw123";
$dbName = "database";

$conectar = mysqli_connect($dbServername, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);
?>
```

Puedes usarla con un `include` de ese fichero y así usarla desde otros:

```
function extFolio($folio)
{
    include 'conexion.php';
    $query = "select FolioParticipanteCG from participantes where FolioParticipanteCG = '".$folio."'";
    $folio=mysqli_query($conectar,$query)or die("Error al seleccionar folio".mysqli_error());//En esta linea es donde me genera el error 
    $folio=mysqli_num_rows($folio);
    mysqli_close($conectar);
    return $folio; 
}
```

Comment: Eso soluciono ese error pero ahora me genera otro que es este :
Fatal error: Cannot declare class DB, because the name is already in use in C:\xampp\htdocs\RegistroCongreso\configuracion\clas_conex.class.php on line 2
donde hago la conexion es exactamente en ese archivo (fichero) (clas_conex.class) pero en ese archivo tengo una clase con el mismo nombre de la instancia que hago en donde me genera el error pero pues eso no sucedia 
$bd= new DB(); esto es lo que me genera el error no se si tenga que ver por el include

Comment: Si estás usando el ejemplo que he puesto no te hace falta lo de `$bd= new DB();` . La conexión en mi ejemplo se hace con el `mysqli_connect`, al hacer el `include` puedes llamar a la variable `$conectar` que almacena los datos de conexión que luego se le pasa a `mysqli_query`.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que esa linea $bd= new DB(); es la instancia de la clase del otro archivo y dentro de esa clase tengo mi función conectar pero no es la unica funcion de dicha clase, entonces aun podre seguir utilizando las demas funciones aunque no haya instanciado($bd= new DB() ) ?

Comment: Mi funcion conectar del otro archivo (clas_conex.class.php) esta asi:
public function conectar()
 {  
  //$conexion = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME); 
  $conexion = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
   if(!$conexion)
    {
     echo "<h3>No se ha podido conectar PHP - MySQL, verifique sus datos.</h3><hr><br>";
    }
  return $conexion;
    }
y si le hago exactamente como me dijiste me sigue apareciendo el error del principio si utilizo la variable conexion en el otro archivo donde tengo el include me dice esto : 
Undefined variable: conexion in....